# How to access values of row 1

Tags: php, html, csv

i would like to place the values of row 1 from my csv file within the td as in the example:

```
<td data-label="Jaar">2014</td>
```

Where in this example the word "Jaar" is cel a1 in my csv file.

```
<?php

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    echo '<table border="1">';

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<thead><tr>';
        } else {
            echo '<tr>';
        }

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                print_r($data[$c]);
            if(empty($data[$c])) {
               $value = "&nbsp;";
            }else{
               $value = $data[$c];
            }
            if ($row == 1) {
                echo '<th scope="col">'.$value.'</th>';
            }else{
                echo '<td data-label=".In here is want to place the values of row 1 or 2 or 3.">'.$value.'</td>';
            }
        }

        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        }else{
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $row++; 
    }

    echo '</tbody></table>';
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

In the php code the second line of the csv file is parsed as td, but i want to place the value of a1 in the first td data-label and the value of b1 into the second td data-label. Can anyone give me a hint.

csv file example:

```
aaaa;bbbb;cccc
1111;2222;3333
11;22;33
```

Comment: CSV file example data is this
aaaa;bbbb;cccc
1111;2222;3333
11;22;33
now, what data you want in first line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save row 1 in a variable:

```
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        $colnames = $data;
    } else {
        echo '<tr>';
    }
```

then you can use it in the remaining rows:

```
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<th scope="col">'.$value.'</th>';
        }else{
            echo '<td data-label="'.$colnames[$c].'">'.$value.'</td>';
        }
```